# How can I analyze patterns rank order data across multiple sets of rankings?

Tags: anova, friedman-test

I had respondents complete a survey in which they ranked five word definitions based on how important they were for 18 different words. I want to see if there are features, like part of speech, that predict whether a ranking will be higher. So I have 18 sets of rankings between 5 items, and I need a way to compare them all together.

I originally tried a point system where each of the 18 words got a score (each 1 ranking was worth 5 points, 2 ranking worth 4 points, etc. and added them up). And I ran an ANOVA with the summed scores. But with only 18 words, I don't think this is enough data for an ANOVA.